# PhoneGap Cordova plugin google maps - Plugin not defined

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

Any Help or suggestions would be great!

I am receiving these errors in my logcat from Android studio

```
05-18 23:02:41.917 13209-13209/? D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///data/user/0/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/index.html: Line 350 : Uncaught ReferenceError: plugin is not defined
05-18 23:02:41.917 13209-13209/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(350)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: plugin is not defined", source: file:///data/user/0/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/index.html (350)
```

I have tried:

- Restarting from scratch - Created multiple new instances of the same
  application
- Different type of installation - Manually and using the terminal
- looking through multiple stack overflow entries and tried removing
  and re-adding back the plugin, android platform, the config file

Plugins:

```
$ phonegap plugins
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.3.4-beta-20180517-1004 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
```

My code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

        var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap("map_canvas");

      }, false);

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    button {
      padding: .5em;
      margin: .5em;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <button id="button">Click me!</button>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Directory:

[image: Directory]

Answer (score 0):

Im not using the cordova plugin for google map, but i use the old way to display the google map and its work. You need to register the google API and get the API ID. It should be something similar to this

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[Your API ID provided by google]&callback=[Your function when API is loaded] "></script>

<script>
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
              zoom: 18,
              center: {lat: [Your map latitude value], lng: [Your map Longitude value]}
            });
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        }

        function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: resultsMap,
                  position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
              } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
              }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I have the API Key and I am able to get it running with Javascript API from Google Maps but I was trying to take advantage of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The cordova-plugin-googlemaps does not run with `$> phongep serve` or `phonegap developer app`.

You must **build and run your project on real device or emulator**.

```
$> phonegap cordova run android
```